# htaccess sub folder appending to URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I guys I am wanting everything from with the folder store which is a folder in the root of my website to point to http://qwerty-demos.co.uk/path/under-construction.html

I currently have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  Redirect 301 /store/ http://qwerty-demos.co.uk/path/under-construction.html
</IfModule>
```

Which works great if I just go to qwerty-demos.co.uk/store but as soon as go to qwerty-demos.co.uk/store/cart for instance the word cart gets appended to the redirect URL for example under-construction.htmlcart

Could anyone point me in the right direction please.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^store.*$ http://qwerty-demos.co.uk/path/under-construction.html[r=301,L]
```

Try this hope it helps